# Software to totally drain a laptop battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I'm looking to totally drain 2 laptops in order to judge which one has the better battery. They have different software on them though, so I wanted to find software that will absolutely hammer the processor to eliminate any software differences.

These are Dell laptops each with a single core Intel processor and Nvidia Quadro NVS 110M GPU.

Comment: Just run the operating system until the laptop shutsdown.

Comment: I did think of that but I was after a quicker result so I can get on with maintenance on the better one and scrubbing the slower.

Comment: Drain the battery as far as the OS will allow, then start the PC and enter the bios, leave it in the bios until it shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a software to stress your hardware (CPU, RAM, HD I/O, GC). The more you use them, the more power they will need.

Comment: I wasn't sure what software to use! Something like WPrime?

Comment: I've settled on OCCT. Cheers!

Comment: @MilesHayler: It would be nice if you might be able to write an own answer based on your experience with OCCT :)

Comment: I'm planning on it once I'm all done!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and ran `OCCT` on infinite and it killed one laptop in 45 minutes, while the other was still fine. Saved me a lot of time matching software installs, or timing it twice in the same machine.